# How to write script for incremental backup in Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, backup

I want to implement incremental backup in Ubuntu, so I am thinking of finding md5sum of all files from source and target and check if any two files have same md5sum then keep that file in destination else if different copy the file from source into directory.
I am thinking of doing this in bash
Can anyone help me with the commands of how to check md5sum of two files in different directories ?
Thanks in advance!!

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #
 SOURCE="/home/pallavi/backup1" 
 DEST="/home/pallavi/BK"
 count=1

 TODAY=$(date +%F_%H%M%S)
  cd "${DEST}" || exit 1
  mkdir "${TODAY}"

  while [ $count -le 1 ]; do 
  count=$(( $count + 1 ))
  cp -R $SOURCE/* $DEST/$TODAY
  mkdir "MD5"
  cd ${DEST}/${TODAY}
  for f in *;do
    md5sum "${f}" >"${TODAY}${f}.md5"
  echo ${f}
  done
  if [ $? -ne 0 ] && [[ $IGNORE_ERR -eq 0 ]]; then
  #error or eof
   echo "end of source or error"
   break
  fi
  done
```

Comment: What have you tried? It's easier to start from there. Or maybe try [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org) - I switched to that when I found out, the hard way, that my custom backup solution was, uh, lacking.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I need to implement without any utility..

Comment: Since you're going to use `md5sum` maybe you can use `cmp` instead. Without any utility means your going to write your own from scratch.

Comment: will it work with two md5sum in different folders? Also I want to do it on loop for each file in folder

Comment: It should work, yeah. what have you tried so far?

Comment: i have copied the entire directory using cp and created md5 for each file. i want to compare md5 of each source file with already evaluated md5 one by one..if it doesnt matches and of same file copy that file and remove old one, how can i write script for this scenario whether its a modified file or new file

Comment: Post and explain what have you done, before you attract down votes rather answers. also `GNU cp(1)`  has the `-u` flag, just sayin.

Comment: If files from `source` and `destination` is the same keep it and if they don't match? what will happen?

Comment: I will copy it as well as its MD5 in destination

Comment: Copy to where? a new directory?

Comment: yes source and destination are different directory..

Answer (score 0):

This is `reinventing the wheel` sort of thing.

There are some utility written for this kind of purpose, to name a **few**.

```
rsync
```

GNU `cp(1)` has the `-u` flag.

```
cp
```

For comparing files

```
cmp
```

```
diff
```

For finding duplicates

```
fdupes
```

```
rmlint
```

Here is what I've come up with `re-inventing the wheel` sort of thing.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob

declare -A source_array

while IFS= read -r -d '' files; do
  read -r source_hash source_files < <(sha512sum "$files")
  source_array["$source_hash"]="$source_files"
done  < <(find source/ -type f -print0)

source=$( IFS='|'; printf '%s' "@(${!source_array[*]})" )

while IFS= read -r -d '' files0 ; do
  read -r destination_hash destination_files < <(sha512sum "$files0")
  if [[ $destination_hash == $source ]]; then
    echo "$destination_files"  FOUND from source/ directory
  else
    echo "$destination_files"  NOT-FOUND from source/ directory
  fi
done < <(find destination/ -type f -print0)
```

- Should be safe enough from files with spaces and tabs and new lines, but since I don't have files with new lines so I can't really say.
- Change the action from the `if-else` statement depending on what you want to do.
- Ok maybe `sha512sum` is a bit over kill, change it to `md5sum`
- Add `set -x` after the shebang to see what's actually being executed, good luck.